# javascript: How to detect SVG in HTML img element support?

Tags: javascript, svg, detect

javascript: How to detect SVG in HTML img element support?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
x = new Image();
x.onload = function(){
  if (x.width) {
   alert('svg in img tag supported!');
  }
};
x.src = 'test.svg';
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118254/reliably-detecting-img-tag-support-for-svg

Comment: it's not duplicate, here i answer "svg in img tag", not "inline svg in html5"

Answer (score 2):

A good discussion/comparison of methods is here:
http://www.voormedia.nl/blog/2012/10/displaying-and-detecting-support-for-svg-images

Based on that page, I wound up using this:

```
svgsupport = document.implementation.hasFeature("http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Image", "1.1")
```

Comment: @Yaffle Did this work for you?  Accept answer nudge?

Answer (score -1):

Use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) for feature detection like this.

```
if (Modernizr.SVG){
    //svg supported
}
```

Comment: That does not check for support in an img element.