# Apache Server not serving SVGs

Tags: apache, svg, server

What settings do I need to set in order to make Apache serve SVGs?

**What I found:**

These questions document the use of .htaccess to serve the SVGs with the correct MIME type "image/svg+xml" [SVG images not displaying on certain web servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817577/svg-images-not-displaying-on-certain-web-servers) / https://mid.as/kb/00134/configuring-server-to-handle-svg-images / https://davidwalsh.name/serve-svg-image

This question handles the [Requested URL not found](https://serverfault.com/questions/836670/requested-url-not-found-when-file-not-in-url)

None of these helped resolve this issue.

**Files:**

.htaccess:

```
AllowOverride All

RewriteEngine on

AddType image/svg+xml svg
```

**Folder structure:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

**Other:**

Different files like .png work. I also tested it with Node (npx http-server) which worked.

Comment: I just found out that for some reason if you put it in the folder icons it will not work, but if you put it in any other it will! Take a look at this: https://serverfault.com/questions/153177/apache2-and-icons-path-behaving-differently

Answer (score 1):

AFAICR any recent version of Apache should have the SVG MIME type already configured. You shouldn't have to do it yourself unless you are running a very old version.
Anyway, a misconfigured MIME type wouldn't casue a 404.  I think something else must be going on.

If you haven't already, try looking at the Network tab in your browser dev tools, and the Apache access log to check whether you are actually fetching the URL you think you are.  And check that the file permissions are set correctly.  Does the file have the correct owner, group, and permissions to be accessed by apache?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this behavior comes from the `alias` module which comes enabled by default and also loaded with an example configuration.

The example configuration defines an alias for the `icons` directory. This means that every requests to that directory are redirected to the defined alias.

Two possible solutions:

1. disable the `alias` module.
2. remove the pre-defined alias to the `icons` directory in the file `mods-available/alias.conf`.