# How do I embed SVG into a single hta/htm document?

Tags: css, svg, embed, hta

My end goal here is to use the svg image for a css background like so:

```
#somelement {
  background: transparent url(#embededSvg) repeat-x;
}
```

I need (want*) two things to work,
  1. The svg is embeded into the document (but not rendered like an  block) witch I can achive with:

```
    Skip<svg ... style="display:none;">...</svg>
```

1. The svg to loop on its x axis as a css background (without packing extranious files with the hta/htm document).

I've tried creating the svg as a Javascript Image object and setting the objects innerHtml to be the svg but I'm not sure how I would referance the Image object in css.

Comment: If I recall, one point that I missed when I asked this question is that the base64 of an embded image must also be uri-encoded.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea and you would link the SVG the same as the image file would be linked like so:

```
<style>
  #somelement {background: transparent url('someimage.svg') repeat-x;}
</style>
```

Or even like this:

```
<style>
  #somelement {background: transparent url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNzUiIGhlaWdodD0iMjc1Ij48L3N2Zz4%3D') repeat-x;}
</style>
```

Not all browsers support SVG in CSS backgrounds.  Browser support for this is shown here:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-css

Comment: Also note that SVG files that are generated on the fly may take longer than the page load which can cause problems! Check this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759427/javascript-how-can-i-delay-returning-a-value-for-img-complete

Answer (score 0):

**SVG can be added into the page in 6 ways**
They are :

#### **1) Object tag**

#### **3) Iframe**

#### **4) Inline SVG**

#### **5) IMG tag**

### **6)** Css

See this: https://www.sitepoint.com/add-svg-to-web-page/

#### SVG with background repeat

See this:-[Why background-repeat: no-repeat doesn't work with .svg images in Opera 12?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819153/why-background-repeat-no-repeat-doesnt-work-with-svg-images-in-opera-12)

It will be like this
`{background:url('image.svg ') repeat-x;}`