# Why background-repeat: no-repeat doesn't work with .svg images in Opera 12?

Tags: css, svg, opera, background-repeat

I got stuck with a strange problem in Opera 12: I have an `.svg` image which is linked within my css code. When I resize to zoom-out the page where the image is displayed, `Opera` repeats the image as if I didn't use the "no-repeat" value in background-repeat.  What am I missing?

Here is my css code:

```
.svgImg {
    background: url("../img/img.svg") no-repeat;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

I also tried this:

```
.svgImg {
     background: url("../img/img.svg");
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     height:100%;
     width:100%;
 }
```

But it didn't work.
Why opera does that?

Comment: Try to remove the `width` and `height` attributes in the SVG. [See answer here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859995)

Comment: Why bother supporting Opera?

Comment: I have tried to remove rhe width and height but it still don't work. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Does it work in opera 15 or newer? If so, it's likely an issue with presto, which opera dropped for chromium layout engine in 15 and newer.

Comment: Also, have you verified that the issue is only with SVG images? Do you get the expected behavior when you change the background-image to png or jpeg?

Comment: Didn't try on a newer version cause I am using Linux and actually the latest version for it is 12. Guess I should not worry to much about it anyway cause it is quite an old version.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
background-repeat:no-repeat!important;
```

Worked for me on Firefox v.88

Answer (score -2):

```
.svgImg {
background: url("../img/img.svg") no-repeat;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation with your answers. It will helps others understand your reasoning.